# The below given code is returning null when I am loading the property file

Tags: java

The code sample given below returns null value.
Directory structure for your reference is :
**D:\Postcard_workspace_new\Postcard_workspace\ConfigMigrationUtility\ConstantFiles** ->contains the constants.properties file

**D:\Postcard_workspace_new\Postcard_workspace\ConfigMigrationUtility\src\configmigrator\utility** ->contains below given java class

Code :

```
 public class PropertyUtil {
  public static Properties prop;
  public static Properties constantProp;
  constantProp = new Properties();
 public static void loadPropertyFile(String inputfilename) {

 try {

    // Loads the constants.properties file
    InputStream constantPropFile = ClassLoader.class
            .getResourceAsStream("/ConstantFiles/constants.properties");
    System.out.println(constantPropFile);//prints null
    constantProp.load(constantPropFile);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    // e.printStackTrace();
    log.equals("Constant Property file not found");

} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    // e.printStackTrace();
    log.error("Can't Load constants.properties property  
 file ");
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: `D:\Postcard_workspace_new\Postcard_workspace\ConfigMigrationUtility\ConstantFiles` is not on the classpath unless you have configured it so. This is `D:\Postcard_workspace_new\Postcard_workspace\ConfigMigrationUtility\src\ ` the start of your classpath. This excludes the file you are trying to access.

Comment: Then what do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Place the file `constants.properties` at the following location:

```
D:\Postcard_workspace_new\Postcard_workspace\ConfigMigrationUtility\src
```

And access it using this:

```
InputStream constantPropFile = ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/constants.properties");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in eclipse then include that properties file's folder in src folder. Else just copy that properties file and paste in the src folder. Because At the runtime jvm finds the file in src folder.

Answer (score 0):

if you add "ConstantFiles" folder to your project build path, you can access it using ClassLoader.class
            .getResourceAsStream("/constants.properties");
(If you are using eclipse, right click on project > build path > configure build path > add folder on source tab)